# Java - Mnemonic underline position

Tags: java, mnemonics

Say I have a JMenuItem who's name is "This is a Test". If I want to set it's mnemonic to 'T', it automatically underlines the first T in "This". Can I change this, so it underlines the T in "Test" instead?

Answer (score 1):

Simply call `setDisplayedMnemonicIndex(int index)` on  your JMenuItem or on any object of a class derived from AbstractButton. See the [API listing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setDisplayedMnemonicIndex-int-) for this.